# Django: Using static, hard time with paths to render css

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

This is a bit embarrassing, but I don't know how to solve this problem:

First off, my project directory looks like this (there are more directories, but we aren't concerned with them):

```
projectfolder/
   wsgi/
     openshift/
         templates/
             home/
                simple-sidebar.html
     static/
        css/
        fonts/
        js/
```

And the file we are concerned with is `simple-sidebar.html` which looks like the following :

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href= "{% static "css/bootstrap.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Add custom CSS here -->
<link href="{% static "css/simple-sidebar.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static "font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
```

Now for some reason my static template tags are not working, but that's probably because I don't know how to set up my static template stuff in my `settings.py`:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, '..', 'static')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = ()    <--- dont know if I need this one?

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)
```

PS: Also how would you do this without the {% static %} tag? I am not sure how my style sheets `href` would look like.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the dots from your STATIC_ROOT, for example

`STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static')`

`STATICFILES_DIRS` are there for you if you'd like to map additional folders to your application that can be anywhere on your machine. When you run `./manage.py collectstatic` you're essentially asking python to find all the files within said directories and drop them into the static folder defined in `STATIC_ROOT`

If you would like to map your files manually (without the static tag) you'd have to write out the full path of your file, for example `/some/directory/path/css/style.css`.

Lastly if you're running with `DEBUG = True` you are required to add your static and media urls to `urls.py` so there is an actual path in place. For example

```
from django.conf import settings

# ... your normal urlpatterns here

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
        'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
        (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
        'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}))
```